# ISO passes SHA tests, but deb packages on installation don't match MD5

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 in VMware, and every time I try it reports that several files in the iso are corrupt. I have tried re-downloading several times and it has not helped. What can I do?

- 9c21c99bab91462b6ca779bfcaccb1de466b9ad0309a9dbd6d196b4918cc72ef *ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso
- Provided 9c21c99bab91462b6ca779bfcaccb1de466b9ad0309a9dbd6d196b4918cc72ef - Check output x.x looks fine, guess ill try another mirror.
- I tried another mirror and got the same thing. The `./pool/main/s/sphinx/python-sphinx_1.1.3+dfsg-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb file failed the MD5 checksun verification. Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.` Could it be a bad release?

Comment: Check the SHA-256 hash of the downloaded ISO to make sure it equals the SHA-256 given. If not, try a different mirror.

Comment: 9c21c99bab91462b6ca779bfcaccb1de466b9ad0309a9dbd6d196b4918cc72ef *ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso - Provided

9c21c99bab91462b6ca779bfcaccb1de466b9ad0309a9dbd6d196b4918cc72ef - Check output

x.x looks fine, guess ill try another mirror

Comment: If they do match, then your ISO is *not* corrupt. Where is it giving the "corrupt" error message?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I tried another mirror and got the same thing.
`The ./pool/main/s/sphinx/python-sphinx_1.1.3+dfsg-2ubuntu2.1_all.deb file failed the MD5 checksun verification. Your CD-ROM or this file may have been corrupted.`
Could it be a bad release? EDIT: That was on a disk check after it failed to install.