# unable to install Ubuntu Cloud setup on VMWare

Tags: 12.04, server, cloud

I guess this is trivial and most commonly asked question, but I'd reiterate it again here as I'm not able to find a correct solution.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Cloud setup on VMWare using the package from http://download.ubuntu.com and have this basic installation setup issue as per the below image.

```
file:///cdrom/pool/main/k/klibc/klibc-utils_1.5.25-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb was corrupt
```

The issue is I cannot continue by skipping this as you know this happens to be the most important setup.

How can I fix this?
Help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/193892/iso-passes-sha-tests-but-deb-packages-on-installation-dont-match-md5

Comment: Sound either like a bad ISO or the server where you got it from has messed up the ISO. Can you get it from another location?

Comment: But that's gross! Ubuntu is releasing a bad ISO for it's cloud?! And that too 12.04, the latest version? I downloaded it from the Ubuntu website, bro.

Comment: So? Only need to have 1 bad sector on a harddisc and the ISO becomes a problem. Report it to the ppl that are responsible ;)